# Error: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'get_user_info'

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm currently programming my own discord bot.
Now i'm trying, to do that, when the bot startet it sends a dm to me.

This is my code

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
      owner = await bot.get_user_info(my Userid)
       await bot.send_message(owner, "Ready", tts=True)
```

but i'm always getting the error:

> AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'get_user_info'

and i have done some research but i found literally nothing
i hope you guys can help me:)
i appreciate it

Comment: what's `my Userid` ? Pretty sure you can't have a space there. You also can't just get a user out of nowhere, you need to get it from a guild

Answer (score 0):

`get_user_info` is not a valid attribute of Bot. The correct use would be `get_user` in order to get a User from a valid user ID.

Also, in order to send a message, you need to have a message channel object. Since you're working with DMs, you'll need to create one using the `User.create_dm()` function discord.py offers. Afterwhich you can then send a message.

A lot of what I referenced can be found in the [discord.py documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).

Below is how I solved this issue:

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", intents = intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    owner = bot.get_user(my Userid) # Assuming 'my Userid' is an integer based user id like 278688959905660928
    dm_channel = await owner.create_dm()
    await dm_channel.send("Ready", tts=True)
```

Comment: But then the error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_dm' appears

Comment: That error would mean the bot wasn't able to get a valid user object and store inside of the owner variable. Make sure that 'my Userid' is an integer and not a string, also make sure that you have member intents properly included in order for this to work. I'll edit my code to show the intents I used for this solution.